# Deploy nodejs lambda by serverless met layer size exceeded error

Tags: node.js, lambda, node-modules, serverless

I want to deploy my aws lambda by `serverless`, the repo is here: https://github.com/Jeff-Tian/serverless-space.

Basically it's a nest serverless app, and I configured my `serverless.yml` to use layer manager so I can put my `node_modules` into that layer.

I installed the production-only node_modules so the size is only 93M. But if I ran `serverless deploy` then the error occurs, claiming my unzipped size exceeds 250M.

Then I checked my node_moudles size again by `du -h -d 0 node_modules`, it shows it's 400+ M now.

So I guess the `serverless deploy` installed extra packages to my node_modules, and can be fixed by install serverless plugins globally. But unfortunately there is no this kind of option: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3319#issuecomment-303080193.

Can anyone shed some lights here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently can workaround it by

```
npm install -g serverless
npm install -g serverless-plugin-names

serverless deploy
```